# How to obtain terms defined by a recursion relation in terms of the first value without solving the recursion?

Tags: matrix, recursion, code-request

I have a set of coefficients $A_{i}^N$ where $i=0,\dots, N$ that obey a recursion relation that takes the form

$$A_i^N = C_i^N-\sum_{M=1}^N\sum_{k=0}^{N-M}A_k^{N-M}\psi_{i,k}^{N,M}$$

The coefficients $C_i^N$ and $\psi_{i,k}^{M,N}$ are known. So if we prescribe $A_0^0$ the recursion relation defines all $A_i^N$.

I wanted to use Mathematica to implement this and starting from a given value of $A_0^0$ determine any $A_i^N$ I choose as a function of $C_i^N$ and the appropriate $\psi_{i,k}^{N,M}$.

Now, I'm not sure how to do this. I know about RSolve that tries to explicitly solve a recursion relation. This one is too complicated and I don't expect it even to be possible to give one general formula for all $A_i^N$. What I want is a bit different than RSolve. What I want is really give $A_0^0$ and evaluate any $A_i^N$, say $A^2_0$ and get it symbolically in terms of the coefficients that are known.

How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't `A[0,0]` already prescribed to be `C[0,0]`?

Comment: No, because the recursion relation only applies for $N\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display index variables as [`Subsuperscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsuperscript.html)

```
(Format[#[i_, n_]] := Subsuperscript[#, i, n]) & /@ {A, c};

Format[ψ[i_, k_, n_, m_]] := 
  Subsuperscript[ψ, Row@{i, ",", k}, Row@{n, ",", m}];
```

Use [`memoization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) to trade storage use for efficiency.

```
A[i_Integer?NonNegative, n_Integer?Positive] := A[i, n] =
  c[i, n] - Sum[A[k, n - m]*ψ[i, k, n, m], {m, 1, n}, {k, 0, n - m}]
```

Example:

```
A[0, 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficient?

```
A[i_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
  C[i, n] - Sum[Sum[A[k, n - m] Psi[i, k, n, m], {k, 0, n - m}], {m, 1, n}]

A[0, 2]
(* C[0, 2] - (C[0, 1] - A[0, 0] Psi[0, 0, 1, 1]) Psi[0, 0, 2, 1] - 
   A[0, 0] Psi[0, 0, 2, 2] - Psi[0, 1, 2, 1] (C[1, 1] - A[0, 0] Psi[1, 0, 1, 1]) *)
```